# Custom format in Excel for numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have entered the number in a cell as 2978421. The number is being displayed as 29,78,421.
I want the number to be displayed as 2,978,421. I want to know the format to be typed in customs box.

Answer (score 1):

On your cell enter 2978421 then navigate to format:

Right click cell > Format Cells...

Ensure 'Number' is selected from the right hand side followed by checkbox 'Use 1000 Separator'

[image]

Hope this solves your problem.